# Multi destinations for Kinesis stream at same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Can we have multiple destinations from single Kinesis Streams?
I am getting output in Splunk but now I also want to add an S3 bucket as the destination.
If I add another Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose, will it affect the performance of Splunk reading? Splunk pulls directly from Kinesis. If I add another destination will it affect Will it affects our current read and writes?

Comment: Welcome. Perhaps this may answer at least the first part of your question. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/enhanced-consumers.html. Also to avoid down votes I suggest you separate the firehose performance issue as a separate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the benefits of using Kinesis is that you can do exactly this behaviour.

Each consumer application becomes responsible for which events it has read from the shard. There is no concept of an entry being processed already between 2 seperate applications.

One [recommendation from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/building-consumers.html) to bare in mind for high throughput for multiple consumers is to use enhanced fanout.

> Each consumer registered to use enhanced fan-out receives its own read throughput per shard, up to 2 MB/sec, independently of other consumers.

Comment: Is this possible also with Firehose? I'm trying to use the same delivery stream to write into multiple destinations, without success.